# Define the range of a function in Sympy (Python 2.7)?

Tags: python, range, sympy

I'm working on a project that uses Sympy to define a series of two-variable functions with the Eq() statement (Such as: "Eq(j, Abs(i))"), later 'sympify's the expressions, then later replaces one of the variables with a known value and solves for the missing value.

My question though is how, if possible, can I define a range for this work work over? For example: using the equation above, j = |i|, if I only want answers for j over -5 > i > 5 is there an elegant way to have it return False for anytime it plugs in an i not in that range?

Comment: I take it you really mean `-5 < i < 5`

Comment: Ah, ya. Accidental typo.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine equalities and inequalities using boolean operators `And`, `Or`, and `Not` (you can also use the `&`, `|`, and `~` operators, respectively).

I would create a boolean expression representing the constraint you wish to satisfy, in this case, `And(-5 < i, i < 5)`, and substitute the solution in it at the end. Something like

```
In [10]: expr = Eq(i, abs(j))

In [14]: constraint = And(-5 < i, i < 5)

In [15]: d = {j: 6}

In [16]: sols = solve(expr.subs(d), dict=True)

In [17]: sols
Out[17]: [{i: 6}]


In [21]: for sol in sols:
   ....:     full_d = d.copy()
   ....:     full_d.update(sol)
   ....:     print(constraint.subs(full_d))
   ....:
False
```

Note that I have allowed the constraints to include both known and unknown values here. If they only contain unknown values, you don't need to copy and update the dictionary of known values. You'll probably want to wrap this up in a function.